# Is there an ability that allows you to complete objectives faster?

Tags: call-of-duty-ww2

In War there is a series of primary objective to complete, along with side objectives. Side objectives include things like repairing walls and barricades, and planting bombs to blow up barricades, and setting up MG nests. Primary objectives include things like escorting a tank, planting C4 on a bombsite, and repairing objectives.

Is there any division or any ability that allows for faster objective completion, or is objective completion speed the same across all divisions?

Comment: I'd say anything that comes with smoke grenades is useful, but I haven't seen or read about speeding up things like repairing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't an ability/perk that directly increases the speed at which you complete objectives.